# preventing fraud by visitors using firebug or other consoles

Tags: javascript, firebug

I am trying to prevent fraud in a webproject I am building.
The project is a game which includes multiple websites.

Each website does a ajax check for with each pageview to a webpage on my server for a status update of the game.
The response page, lets say www.domain.com/response.cfm (it is coldfusion) normally returns nothing, but at a certain point of time within the games timeframe, it will display a JSON string with information. 
This information is then used by the script that is included on the websites.

So website A has been viewed 100 times (all of its pages), which will generate 100 ajax calls.

The problem I have is that a robot could check the ajax destination too, and much faster. Now I can detect a robot, or could make it difficult for him by using a session or checking for cookies, BUT...

the biggest issue is that I found out you can do a lot in the Firebug script console, or the Safari console. Probably Chrome too.

With this console, they can even evade the crossdomain restriction. I created a simple script that does a couple of calls to the Ajax page and when I go to the same domain first, and then use the console...there is no crossdomain limitation. And you execute all kind of javascript, so in essence someone like me could commit fraud in the game by using the javascript console which masks him as regular browser user.

My question now is: Does anyone know how to prevent this? I tried to disable the usage of the console but I don't think I can. It may be possible to detect if the console is active and then disable MY scripts so the game doesn't work. But I think they can load the script source in the console manually and then the game does work.

Looks like console is a beautiful thing, but a nightmare for me now to prevent people cheating in the game I am creating.

Hope anyone has suggestions.

ps: of course I am trying to implement som server side checks to detect cheating, but most of the time it is not realtime.

---

UPDATE 19/3/2012

---

The fraud that I am trying to prevent is cheating in the game by polling the page that generates logic for the next step of the game. This is a serverscript page which generates json code which will trigger a change on the website the game is played on. For your information, websites the are involved have a script in there header, like google analytics, so they will communicate with my server every pageview.

Polling that serverpage can reveal information which will gain the cheaters knowledge or progress.

So i have to prevent people from getting knowledge ahead of other earnest players by monitoring the serverpage which will reveal information at a certain time. I don't want them auto polling it and when info is revealed, the send themselves a notifcation and check the website.

So what I will do is make sure that if people have to many pageviews per second, they are blocked. Plus you need a cookie to be able to join in and you only get a cookie by logging in. Hopefully this will give me enough tools to make it as robust as possible.

Thanks for all your knowledge, people.

Comment: what types of "fraud" do you want prevented?

Comment: There are other ways for the user to run custom JS code in your page - greasemonkey, browser extensions, even `javascript:` in the address bar. I wouldn't waste time on blocking console. (In certain browsers you might be able to read arguments.callee.caller and see if any callers look like the console, but that is deprecated, browser-dependant and unreliable.)

Comment: Even if you could block the console, a determined hacker could use an intermediate proxy like Fiddler to intercept and generate those calls.

Comment: I realized that I cannot control anything on the browser and all the checks have to be at the server

Answer (score 6):

It would be very, very difficult to disable web consoles across the majority of browsers, and anyone who managed to do this would probably be exploiting a browser bug. But read on...

First rule of web programming: You can **never** trust anything you receive from the web client. Anything that gets sent to your data might have been forged or altered intentionally or unintentionally, and even if you did manage to block a web console, what's to stop me from opening it in a different browser which specifically disallows websites with the console? So that's out. As @DCoder mentions in the comments, there are other methods as well, including browser extensions, which would allow user-defined JavaScript to be executed.

So any checking you do has to be server side. I know you're trying to do some checking already, and it's hard to give advice without having more specifics. That said, one way to do this, as far as I can see right now, is to issue each client an ID and store that in a database somewhere. They can't be sequential IDs, and make sure that they're not trivially forgeable even if someone has a bunch of different IDs (for example, you might want to salt the username, and then hash it). Each time a request is made to the server, only issue a response if the last request was >500 ms ago, and update the database accordingly. Expire the ID after logoff or some time.

Comment: Yes, I was think using a session variable which expires and is linked to a transaction, but I do have to think it through carefully because from the console they could also create a valid session. The interval between the requests can give me some insight. But if I wanted to cheat, I would setup random intervals to fool the website.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should think about is securing your server, not the client. It's impossible to hide client code from the client. While it might arguably help prevent a few people who want to cheat from cheating, it's not your primary objective. You have to do this from the server side. This means validating the requests on the server to ensure that they conform to your expectations to some degree.

Game companies will

1. Require user authentication of some kind so they can identify users
2. Create some rules about possibilities. For example, the laws of physics should apply, so you know when someone has cheated. Something they can validate as human activity.
3. Ban people who cheat

If you are not sending data continuously over the network, then you have an issue which is unsolvable unless you are willing to make checks on the server securely and continuously over the course of the game. This will increase server load, but that's the unfortunate cost of preventing cheats.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my worry. The server load to check requests. The traffic could get quite large if a lot of websites are involved an a lot of users. Every page refresh on any website that is involved in the game creates a pageview, call to the webserver. I can always try to detect cheating afterwards, but then they would already have partly ruined the game for the current players. I have simplified the server entries to one page only which generates the javascript logic sent to the client. This way I think I have hidden more logic on the server.