# Dev Tools Chrome with JQuery you can enable / disable stuff

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I just figured something out.

I'm using Chrome browser, and if a website is using JQuery you can then use Chrome dev tools to execute javascript to alter the website i.e. Enable buttons which shouldn't be enabled.

if you run the normal code `document.getElementById('myId').disabled = false` or `document.getElementById('myId').enabled = true` then it does nothing.

But as soon as you run `$('#myId').attr('disabled', false);` then the component actually enables and you are then able to click it.

Is it possible with JQuery to block out these type of executions?

Comment: No. That's why it's called Dev Tools - to enable developers to do such things. Move business logic to server.

Comment: An input element doesn't have any property `enabled`. Are you thinking of `disabled`? `document.getElementById('myId').disabled = true` - this works fine in devtools

Comment: Yes sorry, that slipped my mind, couldn't remember which one.

Comment: *"if a website is using JQuery you can then use Chrome dev tools to execute javascript to alter the website"* ... you can also use the dev tools if the website does not use jQuery.

Comment: With the dev tools you can change  html code, load other script files you could do anything, even if there was initially no library loaded. Javascript (no matter if and what library is used) is just for eyecandy and to improved usability. You always have to validate the correctness of the actions that should be done and the data you received once again on your server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [preventing fraud by visitors using firebug or other consoles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756562/preventing-fraud-by-visitors-using-firebug-or-other-consoles)

Answer (score 3):

So are you asking if you can use jQuery to prevent people from running additional javascript/jQuery from the browser console? No, you cannot do this, the console is built into the browser for developers to test and experiment with by running additional javascript after/while javascript on the page is running.  Same thing goes for other browsers as well.